# HTML tag redirect blocking

Tags: html

I'm using following code for just dialog box, Its working fine.. But how can I stop from redirecting the same page while clicking?

```
<a href="" title = "this is some text">[?]</a>
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: `event.preventDefault()` is what you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to link anywhere: Don't use a link in the first place.

```
<span title = "this is some text">[?]</span>
```

(If you are creating something to click on (which triggers JS) then use a `<button>`).

Answer (score 2):

add the # like so :

```
<a href="#" title = "this is some text">[?]</a>
```

or remove href of link and set url in some custom attribute

onclick event of link, read url from custom attribute

```
<a href="#" onclick="JSFunction()" id="someid" data-url="some url">text</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

You may try this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.click', function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     e.stopImmediatePropagation();
     return false;
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/u4jga/3/)